# flexibility of meaning between 恋に破れる vs 血に飽きた

Tags: grammar

A more specific question regarding a [reply i got from a more long winded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62567/%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1-intransitive-verbs-vs-%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0-intransitive-verbs-when-taking-%E3%81%AB/62663#62663). Hopefully i can expand this to other situations.

> Aくんも私と同じように、恋に破れて泣く日が来るんだろうか
>
> ～に破れる means either "to be defeated by ～" or "to be heartbroken
>   regarding ～" depending on the context.
>
> A-kun just like me, is "broken due to" love, ....

compared something such as

血に飽きたときは、まぁ……これで代用できなくもないわね (as a vampire)

During times when i'm "tired of" blood, ...

If I were to rewrite this as:

> Aくんも私と同じように, 血に飽きて戦い続けてはいられない.
>
> A-kun just like me, has had enough due to the blood, ...

or is

"A-kun just like me, is tired of the blood, ..." the only way to read it?

---

Similarly, why can't you read  Aくんも私と同じように、恋に破れて泣く日が来るんだろうか as

"A-kun just like me, his love(relationship) is broken, ....

---

why or why not?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

A set phrase is a set phrase. There is normally only one way to interpret it. "Look at the school!" usually means observing the school itself, not observing something else after going to the school, even though a dictionary clearly says *at* marks the place where the action happens. It's because *to look at X* is an English set phrase. By convention, the combination of *look* and *at* has a fixed meaning. Likewise, "I'm interested in the room" does not usually mean I feel interested while I am sitting in the room.

X**に**飽きる almost always translates to *to be tired **of** X* or *to get bored **with** X*. These are fixed set phrases with the shared fixed meaning. You have to memorize them. Although the Japanese particle に and the English prepositions *of/with* have lots of functions, practically speaking, there is no ambiguity here.

That being said, sometimes a combination of a verb and a particle has more than one meaning depending on the noun used with it. The function of に in 暗闇に光る and the function of に in 汗に光る are different. The function of に in ブラジルに敗れる and the function of に in サッカーの試合に敗れる are different. Again, this is something you have to memorize.

Comment: do you mind expanding on 敗れる?  Is it the difference between:  (Xは)サッカーの試合に敗れる  - (X) lost in regards to the soccer match"  and  (Xは) ブラジルに敗れる  - X lost "to" brazil?

Comment: ブラジルに敗れる is "to be defeated *by* Brazil" or "to lose *to* Brazil"; 試合に敗れる is "to lose the match" without any preposition (...according to a dictionary. I'm still learning English and I always have to look up in a dictionary to confirm the correct preposition...)

Comment: I was trying to be more literal with respect to Japanese, since the  試合 itself can't lose, only X can "lose". Which is why I admit  (Xは)サッカーの試合に敗れるる is just slightly confusing. Because X is still the one that is losing, but it really doesn't work well in English became you can both "lose the match" and "lose to an opponent".

Comment: Expanding on this if you don't mind:  (Xは)サッカーの試合に勝つ - i don't think anything changes here compared to 敗れる.         (Xは) ブラジルに勝つ - to gain victory "over" brazil, but there isn't a good way convert "to be ____? by Brazil" in this scenario. Is that just an issue with english or is there anything fundamentally different between 敗れる and 勝つ？

Comment: Let's not try to "be as literal as possible" at the preposition/particle level; it's [too random](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16270/5010), [too arbitrary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39591/5010), [too unpredictable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42909/i-did-a-few-mistakes-vs-i-made-a-few-mistakes) both in English and in Japanese. You can try to be literal at the phrase level. Like it or not, Aは試合に敗れた translates to "A lost the game", and this is something to be memorized.

Comment: I'm looking to confirm this difference between the function of に in ブラジルに敗れる and the function of に in サッカーの試合に敗れる one more time. Is it fair to  say , in ブラジルに敗れる  and ブラジルにかつ, that に is marking  brazil as the agent that did enough  or did not enough to result in X losing/winning (defeating "by" brazil")? Where as in 試合に敗れる/勝つ ,に is  marking the objective/indirect object 試合?

Comment: に in ブラジルに敗れる is [this に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30578/5010), although I have no idea whether "agent" is the correct term.

Comment: Neither do I haha, i don't know a thing about technical grammar terms before studying japanese. Would the usage you linked also apply to 皆が酒に溺れる or 喜びに浸る? or  is this に marking an abstract "location" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what are you asking about, but 血に飽きたときは、まぁ……これで代用できなくもないわね means "when you are fed up with blood, you could substitute this (for blood)", and Aくんも私と同じように, 血に飽きて戦い続けてはいられない means "A-kun, just like me, can no longer keep fighting after being fed up with blood".

Likewise,  Aくんも私と同じように、恋に破れて泣く日が来るんだろうか means "Will A-kun get his heart broken and cry someday just like me?".

Comment: the point was to examine if a change in context/sentence structure could involve a different way to interpret it. In this case it does not, but as naruto pointed out, some cases it does.